# How to recover Mac OS 9 data off of a failed hard drive

Tags: macos, ubuntu, hard-drive, data-recovery, sata

A while ago I used Mac OS 9 and had an external hard drive which failed.

I want to recover my data, but am unsure of the best way to do that.

I [got this cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0919N4XNW): “SATA/IDE to USB 3.0 Adapter, FIDECO USB 3.0 Hard Drive Adapter Cable Universal for 2.5/3.5 inch SATA HDD/SSD & IDE HDD with 12V/2A Power Adapter”

I think my Ubuntu machine would be good for this recovery.

My plan is to install a virtual Mac OS 9 on Ubuntu somehow, plug the drive in the Ubuntu machine and then I’ll be able to access my files. Is that a plan that will theoretically work?

Comment: In what way did the external hard drive fail?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It did not mount I when plugged in.

Comment: FIrst, your whole plan sounds great! But one fairly massive hitch:  “…an external hard drive which failed.” If the drive itself is dead, then that is all there is to say. A dead hard drive is a dead hard drive.

Comment: Ubuntu can read HFS with some additional software. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os

Comment: Hmm but the data was written by Mac OS 9 in the early 2000s. Will Ubuntu still be able to read it?

Comment: HFS can be read with Fuse and related software. But if the drive is dead, the drive is dead.

Comment: Have you already carefully removed the hard drive from its enclosure so that you can attach it to the new adapter? As you may have guessed, it can be the little circuit board in the enclosure which has failed, and not the disk drive.

Comment: Yes I removed the drive _which runs_ but doesn’t mount. Now I watched a video in which this device just copied all of the files on the old hdd to a new hdd but I am not sure if that was the same product so I will read these instructions.